# Pandas Dataframe str split max

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a dataframe with a column that includes individual names. The names are not always in the same format, so I am trying to split out the first and last names into separate columns. For example, I may see:

```
Smith John

Smith, John

Smith, John A

Smith John A

Smith John and Jane
```

The consistent pattern is last name first. How can I create two separate fields for last name then a second column which is everything not last name. Here is what I have so far

```
owners_df['normal_name'] = owners_df['name'].str.replace(', ', ' ')
owners_df['lastname'] = owners_df["normal_name"].str.split(' ', 1)[0]
owners_df['firstname'] = owners_df["normal_name"].str.split(' ', 1)[1]
```

The issue is I get an error "ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index"

Comment: when you run this `owners_df["normal_name"].str.split(' ', 1)[0]` you are grabbing the first row only, are you able to produce a [mcve] and post your expected output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Datanovice already said in comment "when you run this `owners_df["normal_name"].str.split(' ', 1)[0]` you are grabbing the first row only"

use the `.str` accessor to get expected output

```py
owners_df['lastname'] = owners_df["normal_name"].str.split(' ', n=1).str[0]
owners_df['firstname'] = owners_df["normal_name"].str.split(' ', n=1).str[1]
```

[See docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split) Note the `n` parameter to limit the split to one time.

Comment: [See docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas.Series.str.split) Note the `n` parameter to limit the split to one time.  Please add this text to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `.str[0]` and  `.str[1:]` after your split.

```
ser=pd.Series(['Smith John',
'Smith John',
'Smith John A',
'Smith John A',
'Smith John and Jane'])

ser.str.split(' ').str[0]

0    Smith
1    Smith
2    Smith
3    Smith
4    Smith

#leaving off the .str.join will give a list, which may be preferable in some use cases
ser.str.split(' ').str[1:].str.join(' ') 

0             John
1             John
2           John A
3           John A
4    John and Jane
```

If, instead, you just want to move each element toa separate column, you can pass `expand=True`

```
ser.str.split(' ', expand=True)

    0       1       2       3
0   Smith   John    None    None
1   Smith   John    None    None
2   Smith   John    A       None
3   Smith   John    A       None
4   Smith   John    and     Jane
```